# How to make inner div clickable?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the next html:

```
<a href="somelink" class="list-group-item">
    Text
    <div onclick="func()">Content</div>
</a>
```

But when I am clicking on my div `a` is getting an even too. How to prevent subsequent events? I wanna if the user has clicked my `div` then only this `div` would was clicked.

**UPDATED**
Maybe it's not an elegant solution but I have solved my problem so:

```
<button class="list-group-item" type="button" onlick="link('somelink')">
    Text
    <div onclick="func()">Content</div>
</button>
```

Although now it shows a focus highlighter and `outline: none;` didn't help to hide it.

Comment: An `<a>` can not contain interactive content, otherwise it would be invalid.

Comment: @Xufox, I thought it's possible. Thank you, I will switch to `div` an outer node too then.

Comment: also, if you attach a listener to the div that will replace the `a` tag, it will still trigger. use [`event.stopPropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent this

Comment: @Logar, I still need to the hyperlink gets click events too if the user clicked outside `div` but inside `a`.

Comment: @Logar, I see... I'll try the best, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @Шах Uhm… a `<button>` may also not contain any interactive content. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Xufox, thank you! I've solved my problem by Delowar's solution.

Comment: @Xufox, I used `a` or `button` cuz I wanted to save `list-group-item` class without modifications to it still could be interactive (with a highlighter)... I'm a noobie in CSS still, unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure javascript (with `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default action of the link):

```html
<a href = "somelink">
    Text
    <div id="div">Content</div>
</a>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//you may also want to use event.stopPropagation() to stop the event bubbling down the DOM tree
myFunc();
});
function myFunc(){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Function myFunc called.";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**just use the pointer-events property & preventDefault() function to ignore anchor tag:**

```js
$('.somelink').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target);
})
```

```css
.somelink{
  pointer-events: none
}

.somelink > div {
  pointer-events: all
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href"somelink">
    Text
    <div onclick="func()">Content</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, bro! It's that I was needed!